# Front of queue of arrays in C++ STL changing while pushing array into the queue

Tags: c++, arrays, stl, queue

I am trying to implement a queue of arrays in C++ STL, but whenever I push a new array into the queue and try to access the front of the queue it returns me the value of the latest array value added. Here is the code I am using;

```
queue<int*> a;
  int temp[2];
  temp[0]=1;
  temp[1]=1;
  a.push(temp);
  cout<<"front "<<a.front()[0]<<"back "<<a.back()[0]<<"\n";
  cout<<"size: "<<a.size()<<"\n";

  temp[0] = 2;
  temp[1] = 2;
  a.push(temp);
  cout<<"front "<<a.front()[0]<<"back "<<a.back()[0]<<"\n";
  cout<<"size: "<<a.size()<<"\n";
  temp[0] = 3;
  temp[1] = 3;
  a.push(temp);
  cout<<"front "<<a.front()[0]<<"back "<<a.back()[0]<<"\n";
  cout<<"size: "<<a.size()<<"\n";
```

Here is the output of the above code:
[code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRZK7.png)

but i expected the output to be as follows:

```
front 1back 1
size 1
front 1back 2
size 2
front 1back 3
size 3
```

Can anybody explain why it is behaving like this?

Comment: You are pushing pointers, not arrays. The pointers are all the same. You never copy any of the data. Use `std::queue<std::array<int, 2>>` and everything will work.

Comment: [Pro Tip] Stop using pointers and raw arrays.  If you want the queue to hold an array, then use a `std::queue<std::array<T,N>>` or `std::queue<std::vector<T>>`.

Comment: @MaxLanghof  Thanks i got it :)

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks for the tip..:)